# The conditionnal law of a brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

Please, I have a question about the conditionnal law of a brownian motion.

Here is the statement:

We have  $\mathcal{B}_{h}$ the $\sigma$-field generated by the $\left(S_{t_{k}}, k=0, \ldots, N\right)$ with $S_{t}=S_{T_{0}} \exp \left(\sigma W_{t}-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} t+r t\right)$

The law of $W_{u}$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}_{h}$ for $u \in\left[t_{k}, t_{k+1}\right]$, $h=t_{k+1}-t_{k}$, is given by

$\mathcal{L}\left(W_{u} \mid W_{t_{k}}=x, W_{t_{k+1}}=y\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{t_{k+1}-u}{h} x+\frac{u-t_{k}}{h} y, \frac{\left(t_{k+1}-u\right)\left(u-t_{k}\right)}{h}\right)$

I don't know how tu prove this équality.

Thank in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first equation I recognize as the solution of GBM (geometric brownian motion). You could just have said, "let $S_t$ be a GBM". The second equation is the distribution for the Brownian Bridge Problem (have you studied this?), which asks to interpolate a BM between two known points x and y. It is not clear to me how these are related, in particular $S_t$ does not appear at all in the second part, so why mention it. The Brownian Bridge is easy to look up, you will find the derivation in many places (in maybe slightly different notation).

Comment: Yes you're right sorry, my question is just : How to prove that : 
$\mathcal{L}\left(W_{u} \mid W_{t_{k}}=x, W_{t_{k+1}}=y\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{t_{k+1}-u}{h} x+\frac{u-t_{k}}{h} y, \frac{\left(t_{k+1}-u\right)\left(u-t_{k}\right)}{h}\right)$ with $h=t_{k+1}-t_{k}$ and $W_{t}$ a bronwian motion